# Thunar takes a long time to open and close windows in Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: xubuntu

Thunar takes 20 seconds to open windows in Xubuntu 20.04. I had Xubuntu 18.04 installed on the same machine and Thunar opened windows with no delay. I tried changing /usr/share/gvfs/mounts/network.mount/AutoMount=true to AutoMount=false but it didn't solve the problem. Noticing that as root there is no delay opening and closing windows with Thunar, I changed the permisions to the home folder, but it didn't help either. Any solution please?

**Edit:** The above mentioned problem ocurred in an old laptop with a Pentium Dual-Core CPU T4200. After that I installed Xubuntu in a (also old) desktop machine with a Intel Core I3 CPU, and Thunar worked well. Another difference: while in the laptop when pressing the link in Thunar side panel to Search the Net I get an error message saying the specified location is not supported, in the desktop machine there is not such error message.

Comment: I just had this start happening all of a sudden, and it turns out I had copied a bunch of files into the `~/Templates` directory. As soon as I cleaned that directory out the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple workspaces, with multiple Thunar windows open across them, a crash in one of those windows might cause a delay in any attempt to open another Thunar window in another workspace. This was my experience. I was not aware that Thunar had crashed in another workspace.

So check your open Thunar windows. Close [x] any that have crashed - you won't be able to close the window, but you will be given an option to terminate the application. Do so. And you may find it works as normal, while your other open Thunar windows stay open as they were. Not that such a crash happens often, but if it does, it will add a good 30 seconds to any attempt you make to open another Thunar window.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe one of the Google answers can help you:
https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=5959
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/5a76i8/thunar_slow_on_startup/
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1816298
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you alvol. I checked those answers thus the solutions I tried, which did not work. Meantime I installed pcmanfm as I saw it is better ranked than thunar in Slant (https://www.slant.co/versus/7574/7577/~thunar_vs_pcmanfm) and it runs without problems. If I manage to solve the problem with thunar I'll post it here.

Comment: Please consider expanding upon the information contained in the link, just in case the link becomes unusable in the future.

Comment: When comparing Thunar vs PCManFM, the Slant community recommends PCManFM for most people. In the question “What are the best Linux file managers?” PCManFM is ranked 4th while Thunar is ranked 7th. A list of pros and cons for each file manager is detailed in the link I provided above.

Comment: My choice is the Polo file manager, it's much more Total Commander (Double Commander) in Windows like.